# JavaFx not displaying buttons on Linux

Tags: java, linux, maven, javafx, javafx-2

I built a JavaFx Maven application in NetBeans for Windows and then when I set deployment target to Jar and open the application on Ubuntu the application doesnt show any of the buttons that are in it.

The buttons are normal JavaFX buttons with event handlers and a grid layout.

Is there a configuration issue or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What is error that you are getting ?

Comment: There is no error, half the UI just doesnt show up under Linux but shows up under Windows using the same Jar

Comment: It is unclear why it is not loading.There might be more data required.Atleast for main class.

Comment: Are you using the same version of java/javafx on both Windows and Ubuntu?

Comment: Java 8 jdk and jre are installed on both

Comment: Is it Oracle JDK 8 or OpenJDK 8 installed on the Ubuntu box?  There is not much information in your question, I'm not sure that you will be able to get much assistance.

Comment: I don't have much more information? I'm running the Oracle JDK